# Performance difference Mysql 5.6 vs 5.7 with user variables?

Tags: mysql, sql

Having just migrated from MySQL server 5.6 to 5.7 one of the differences is an apparent massive hit on performance when using user session variables.

To simulate rank operation I increment a user variable in the SELECT statement. A trivial simplified example would be:

```
SET @rank:=0;
SELECT @rank:=@rank+1,col1,col2 FROM myTbl WHERE col2 > 1;
```

Using this **exact** statement on both 5.6 server and on the 5.7 server the latter takes roughly four times as long! Everything else identical. This is all part of a larger more complex operation but even the very trivial example I shown above show this behavior.

Removing the user variable I get roughly identical execution times on 5.6 and 5.7

For me this doesn't make sense. Is there some more locking/integrity checks in regards to user variables in 5.7 (compared with 5.6)?

Is there perhaps some different default server setting differences that could explain this behavior?

Any ideas appreciated!

(It is of course trivial to remove user variables and do post processing but I rather just have one "clean" query to give the result directly)

Comment: Post exact versions and settings. Maybe someone might help then. However - `rank` without `ORDER BY` doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Thanks, but the table in the question is actually a view which is already ordered, hence the lack of explicit sorting here. Just realized I also need to rule this out as a view related issue and verify the behavior on plain tables as well.